# Google Datastore, backend error 503 when doing simple querying

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Java to call the Google Cloud to perform a simple query. I get error:

```
com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException: Backend Error
    at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:115)
    at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:81)
    at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.BaseDatastoreFactory$RemoteRpc.call(BaseDatastoreFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:109)
    at com.test.mycode.main(mycode.java:538)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
```

The request made is very simple. It comes done to this one in query format:

```
 query {
  kind {
    name: "thedata"
  }
  filter {
    property_filter {
      property {
        name: "mykey"
      }
      operator: EQUAL
      value {
        string_value: "somevalue"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Just two questions:
- is the setup wrong of the environment?
- is the syntax of the query incorrect? Should it read "kinds" instead of "kind"?

Comment: Using the API explorer the start of the query text looks like:

Comment: `   {
     "query": {
      "kinds": [
       {
        "name": "thedata"
       }
      ]
     }  
    }`

Comment: You should clarify what code you're actually using. Is that JSON? What do you mean by "call the Google Cloud"? Do you mean you're interacting with the [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/)? Be much more specific and somebody would be able to help you.

Comment: The json shown is part of the debug info from the IDE showing what goes to the Google API.  I noticed that both kind and kinds are used....

Comment: Alright, so then if this is just a kind of specialized debug info, why not show the actual code you're using to make the call?